# Entity Framework 4.1 Modifying Object and Child Collection

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

If I have Book object which has a child collection of Comments, Can I update the Book and list of Comments together with entity framework?

I have tried :

```
_context.Books.Attach(book);
_context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(book, EntityState.Modified);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

with no luck...

getting the following error on the first line:

`An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key`

Comment: "with no luck" isn't very descriptive.  What *exactly* happens when you try it?

Comment: I am getting the error: 'An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key'

Comment: On which line?  The `Attach` line?

Comment: Did you `Detatch` the book before you tried to `Attach` it? i.e. can you show the code before this...

Comment: I did not try to detach the book first...Those are the only three lines in my method right now..passing the book object in as a parameter. I am new to EF, as you can tell...

Comment: And where do you create context? Is it the same context used to load the book? If yes you have your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653009/entity-framework-and-connection-pooling/3653392#3653392 Don't reuse context.

Comment: the context is injected via Ninject when I instantiate my repo class(also using the UnitOfWork pattern as described here... http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/16/using-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More than likely you have a circular dependency (Books has a foreign key reference to Comments, and Comments back to Books).  In this case, the UpdateTranslator within EF is unable to determine the dependency order.  As far as I can tell, in this model of development, there is no way to pass a hint to EF to indicate what the order is.

The most common way to solve this (that I have seen) is to do a two-phase commit.  Make a change to the Book, save it, then make a change to Comments, and save that.  I have found that using the [Code First](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/08/announcing-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-release.aspx) approach allows you to be more specific about the relationships and thereby fix many of the problems that I've had.

Edit:
Here's an example:

```
using (var context = new BookContext())
{
    book.Title = "This is the new title";
    context.SaveChanges();

    book.Comments.Add(new Comment("This is a comment"));
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

If there is a circular dependency, you could not do the above with a single call to `SaveChanges`.

Comment: if the code I posted above is attempting to do everything in one call, how can I modify it to split it up into 2 parts?

Comment: I am not certain I actually have a circular dependency...My Comment object has a BookID property, and my Book object has a Comments Navigation property...There is definitely not a circular dependency within the DB itself

Comment: Have you tried doing two separate `SaveChanges` to see if that resolves the issue?  It would be difficult to debug further without a better view of the model.